# Correct way to define propagation delays in VHDL

Tags: design, vhdl, hdl

I'm currently learning VHDL. As an exercise I decided to implement some of the 7400 series chips. Below is the 74153 and while testing it with ghdl/gtkwave it seems to work.

But I'm sure this implementation is naive (lots of repetition, use of extra delayed (*_d) signals, etc). What would be the clean way to implement such a device?

```
--
-- 74153 implementation
-- Dual 4-Line to 1-Line
--

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


entity TTL_74153 is
  port(
  c0, c1, c2, c3: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  sel: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  g: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  y: out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0));
end TTL_74153;

architecture behav of TTL_74153 is
  signal c0_d, c1_d, c2_d, c3_d: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  signal sel_d, g_d: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
begin
  -- delays
  c0_d <= c0 after 11 ns;
  c1_d <= c1 after 11 ns;
  c2_d <= c2 after 11 ns;
  c3_d <= c3 after 11 ns;
  sel_d <= sel after 20 ns;
  g_d <= g after 18 ns;

  -- logic
  y(0) <= '0' when g_d(0) = '1' else
       c0_d(0) when sel_d = "00" else
       c1_d(0) when sel_d = "01" else
       c2_d(0) when sel_d = "10" else
       c3_d(0) when sel_d = "11";

  y(1) <= '0' when g_d(0) = '1' else
       c0_d(1) when sel_d = "00" else
       c1_d(1) when sel_d = "01" else
       c2_d(1) when sel_d = "10" else
       c3_d(1) when sel_d = "11";

end behav;
```

Comment: Usually delays are properties/limitations of the underlying hardware. VHDL isn't really made for simulating that, the development software creates a delay model for it, which is then accounted for during simulation. Regarding your code, you could've used a with/select for the assignment based on `sel_d`, but it's ok like it is.

Answer (score 1):

Delays such as "wait for" and "after" are not synthesizable. That said, they way you separate the input and output datapath seems wierd. I would do something like this:

--
    -- 74153 implementation
    -- Dual 4-Line to 1-Line
    --

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


entity TTL_74153 is
  port(
  c0, c1, c2, c3: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  sel: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  g: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  y: out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0));
end TTL_74153;

architecture behav of TTL_74153 is


  signal mux_out: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
begin
  -- logic
  -- the vector indices aren't necessary, but i prefer them
  mux_out(1 downto 0) <= c0(1 downto 0) when sel = "00" else
                         c1(1 downto 0) when sel = "01" else
                         c2(1 downto 0) when sel = "10" else
                         c3(1 downto 0) when sel = "11" else
                         "00";
 y= "00" when g(0) = '1' else mux_out;


end behav;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the function `to_integer` in `ieee.numeric_std` package, the logic part can be reduced further.

I think the correct way to model propagation delay in VHDL is by using the *transport delay model*.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity TTL_74153 is
  port(
  c0, c1: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); 
  sel, g: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  y: out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0));
end TTL_74153;

architecture behav of TTL_74153 is
  signal sel_d, g_d: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
begin
  -- delays
  sel_d <= transport sel after 9 ns;
  g_d <= transport g after 7 ns;

  -- logic
  y <= transport (not g_d) and (c1(to_integer(unsigned(sel_d))) & c0(to_integer(unsigned(sel_d)))) after 11 ns;

end behav;
```

Comment: Plain delays (instead of "transport") are here closer to reality because the bandwidth of the component is limited.